VBA Excel parse remote file issue
I have a code to search a certain value in a the active workbook sheet, then open a remote workbook located on a sharepoint, and find the value found in the active workbook.
After that, the full result tab should be copied to sheet "Database" in the active workbook.
Weirdly enough sometimes it works, and sometimes it just opens and displays the remote workbook, but does nothing else afterwards.
I have no explanation for that behaviour.
MsgBox "The search value is  " & sponAcc.Offset(0, 1).Value shows the correct search value, so nothing is wrong there.
Excel version is Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20542) 64-bit
Private Sub Search_DB_ANM()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wsVertical As Worksheet, wsDatabase As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sponAcc As Range, foundRange As Range
    
    Dim sharePointPath As String
    
    ' Set references to the workbooks and sheets
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsVertical = wb1.Sheets("Vertical")
    Set wsDatabase = wb1.Sheets("Database")

    ' SharePoint path to the second workbook
    sharePointPath = "https://corp.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Shared%20Documents/XXXX%20YYYY.xlsx"
     
    ' Clear the Database sheet
    wsDatabase.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Find the sponsor account value in workbook1
    lastRow = wsVertical.Cells(wsVertical.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set sponAcc = wsVertical.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find("Sponsoraccount", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    
    MsgBox "The search value is  " & sponAcc.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ' Open workbook2 from SharePoint
    Dim initialScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    initialScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(sharePointPath)

    ' Check if the workbook was opened successfully
    If wb2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to open the workbook."
       GoTo CleanExit
    End If

   If Not sponAcc Is Nothing Then
        ' Search for the content in workbook2
        wb2.Sheets("Algemeen").Select
        For Each wsVertical In wb2.Sheets
            Set foundRange = wsVertical.Cells.Find(sponAcc.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            
            If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
                ' Copy the contents of the found tab to the Database sheet
                foundRange.Worksheet.UsedRange.Copy
                wsDatabase.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

                ' Autofit rows and columns
                wsDatabase.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                wsDatabase.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
                
                ' Exit the loop after finding and copying the data
                Exit For
                GoTo CleanExit
            End If
        Next wsVertical
        
        ' If no value is found after searching all sheets
        If foundRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Unable to find the value."
            GoTo CleanExit
        End If
     
End If

CleanExit:
    ' Close workbook2 without saving and return to workbook1
    If Not wb2 Is Nothing Then wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb1.Activate
    wsDatabase.Activate

    ' Restore initial application settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = initialScreenUpdating
    Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub


Have you tried stepping through the code using F8 or adding some Debug.Print statements so you can track what's going on in the code?  It's pretty rare for VBA to just unexpectedly exit in the middle of a Sub without some kind of error.

Have not yet debug.printed, stepped through it and it looped perfectly, and the only difference between fail or pass is probably the network speed. That is why I used the msgbox to see if it uses the correct values in it's search, which is ok every time.

When calling Open() (even for a SharePoint file, which tends to take longer) I've never seen Excel not wait until the file is open, or fail to give some error if the file was not openable.  If Not sponAcc Is Nothing Then seems to be the place to look, since it allows your sub to exit without doing anything.

Thank you, that helped. Since I added an else line to that, I don't have that behaviour anymore.
